# SASS (.scss) rule to apply when has both nested classes

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using SASS (.scss) for my current project.

**HTML**

```
<div class="colours colours--blue">
  <!-- This should be blue -->
</div>

<div class="colours colours--yellow">
  <!-- This should be yellow -->
</div>

<div class="colours colours--blue colours--yellow">
  <!-- This should be green -->
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.colours {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;

   &--blue {
      background-color: blue;
   }

   &--yellow {
      background-color: yellow;
   }

   &--blue (AND) &--yellow { /* <<< HOW TO CREATE THIS SELECTOR? */
      background-color: green;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the `&` acts almost like a placeholder in Sass. That put, it's easier to just use the interpolation util `#{}` to avoid the string concatenation.

So the answer would be as straight forward as this:

```
.colours {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;

   &--blue {
      background-color: blue;
   }

   &--yellow {
      background-color: yellow;
   }

   &--blue#{&}--yellow {
      background-color: green;
   }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agjamg)

Answer (score 2):

You could use selector functions:

```
@at-root #{selector-unify(selector-append(&, "--blue"), selector-append(&, "--yellow"))} {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Probably best to wrap that up in another mixin so it’s easier to use:

```
@mixin both-colours($a, $b) {
   @at-root #{selector-unify(selector-append(&, "--#{$a}"), selector-append(&, "--#{$b}"))} {
      @content;
   }
}
```

used as

```
@include both-colours(blue, yellow) {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider the use of a variable like below:

```
$c:'.colours';

#{$c} {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;

   &--blue {
      background-color: blue;
   }

   &--yellow {
      background-color: yellow;
   }

   &--blue {
      &#{$c}--yellow { 
        background-color: green;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If this is the only way to do it I'd introduce another class in the DOM to simplify the styles. This would be too complicated to maintain.